# MVC EditorFor Timespan is removing the seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, timespan, editorfor

The editor generated for my Timespan only includes hours and minutes. I would like it to be standard, i.e. hh:mm:ss.

I would have thought the default would be that, which I've tried. I've also tried

```
    [DisplayName("Start Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
```

The view

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchCriteria.StartTime, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchCriteria.StartTime, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
</div>
```

Comment: Per my research, there has been quite a few issues dealing with formatting timespans.. but could you try: `@Html.EditorFor(model => string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", model.SearchCriteria.StartTime), new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use inputmask to get the masking/formatting effect:

1. Add class to your control you want to format e.g. time-mask

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchCriteria.StartTime, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control time-mask"}})`

2. Add reference to jquery.inputmask.bundle package
3. Use the inputmask function.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.time-mask').inputmask("hh:mm:ss", {
            placeholder: "hh:mm:ss",
            showMaskOnHover: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just keep in mind that `TimeSpan` not designed to represent time of day, but it is for showing a duration of period so it is normal to have `TimeSpan` value in negative or longer than 24 hours.

**Update:**

The behavior is normal since [DataType(DataType.Time)] annotation will add type="time" to the input element in your HTML which is a HTML5 attribute used by some of the browsers like Chrome but not FireFox for example. If you want to use the annotation then you need to add an attribute step="1" to the EditorFor so your code will be:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @step = "1" } }).
```

Note this will work on Chrome but not on FireFox, IE 11 and earlier versions.That's why I suggested the other solution.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate the suggestion very much. But I cannot understand why I would need this. Are you surprised by the default behavior? I also tried the approach you suggested but it didn't work but I wouldn't proceed with it even if it did unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: The behavior is normal since `[DataType(DataType.Time)]` annotation will add type="time" to the input element in your HTML which is a HTML5 attribute used by some of the browsers like chrome but not firefox for example. If you want to use the annotation then you need to add an attribute `step="1"` to the EditorFor so your code will be `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @step = "1" } })`. Note this will work on Chrome but not on FireFox, IE 11 and earlier versions.That's why I suggested the other solution.